# Integral who's lower bound can take multiple values

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int _a^2\:\frac{1}{x^2-x} $$ Where $ a $ can be $ 1<a\le 2 $

Would evaluation of this integral be  equal some specific area $A$ or would it's answer lay on a range ? e.g if we take $a$ to be $\lim _{a\to 1} $ then the answer will be $ \infty > \int _a^2\:\frac{1}{x^2-x} $ and if we take $a = 2$  then the answer is $0$. So to this integral would be  $ \infty > \int _a^2\:\frac{1}{x^2-x} \ge 0$  ? Or is there another way going about this problem ?

Comment: And what is the sign of the integral for $a>2{}$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but $a$ can't take values bigger than 2.

Comment: Is it a requirement of the problem? Because otherwise, $a$ can absolutely take values $>2$. But indeed, if $a$ is constrained to $(1,2]$, then you can check the sign of the integrand to prove the integral is nonnegative.

Comment: No, $a$ can only take values $ 1 < a \le 2 $

Comment: Fine. Now what do you want to know? Do you want to compute the integral? Then notice $\dfrac{1}{x^2-x}=\dfrac{1}{x(x-1)}=\dfrac{1}{x-1}-\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I did exactly as your writing and substituting $x$ with the extreme values $a$ can take I get $ \infty > \int _a^2\:\frac{1}{x^2-x} \ge 0 $ Does it resemble a right answer or is there some other way you can evaluate this integral ?

Comment: Yes, you can evaluate the integral, for an arbitrary $a$ in $(1,2]$. Just integrate! It's not a problem that $a$ doesn't have a known numeric value, the integral is $F(2)-F(a)$ where $F(x)$ is a primitive of $\dfrac{1}{x^2-x}$. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm just wandering if my answer was somewhat right. Does you mean that you can just leave $F(2) - F(a)$ as is and do not show the range of values $ \int _a^2\:\frac{1}{x^2-x}  $ can take ?

Comment: You must replace $F(2)-F(a)$ with the correct expression. Usually you don't need to give the range, unless it's explicitly required in the problem statement. However, you must give the valid set of values for $a$, but here it's already a requirement of the program.